# How to make the program create new variables and apply them in a specific way?

Tags: python, variables

say I have variables 'a' and 'b' and I want my program to go:

```
for a in range(n):
    for b in range(n):
        if a**2 + b**2 ==n:
             return (a, b)
        else:
```

Do the same but with a, b, c as in:

```
for a in range(n):
    for b in range(n):
        for c in range(n):
           if a**2 + b**2 + c**2 ==n:
               return (a, b, c)
```

And so on with d, e etc... however many variables it takes to find an answer.

How do I apply this for it go indefinitely until an answer is found? 
How can I make it create new variables, and then add them in the fashion shown above?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide a minimal working code example and a clear description of your issue?

Comment: Please explain what does "_do the same_" mean. Do _what_?

Comment: refer to the FAQ how to ask. [ask]

Comment: Are you trying to determine if `n` is a sum of squares?

Comment: Yes, exactly trying to get to it using squares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to keep in mind: first, `x**2 >= 1` for all non-zero `x`; second, if `c == 0`, then `a**2 + b**2 + c**2 == a**2 + b**2`. Together, they put an upper bound of `n` on the size of the tuples you need to consider.

This means you can use a single loop that iterates over all possible `n`-tuples:

```
from itertools import product

for t in product(range(n), repeat=n):
    if sum(x**2 for x in t) == n:
        return t
```

Comment: oh nice, not sure I get how it works, but it seems to produce very close to what I need. Thank You so much

Comment: Worst case scenario, `1**2 + 1**2 + ... + 1**2 == n`, for the `n`-tuple (1,1,...,1). `product` produces *all* `n`-tuples (0,0,...,0) through (`n-1`, `n-1`, ..., `n-1`). As an exercise, you can figure out how to eliminate all the infeasible tuples, such as the ones where `sum(t) > n`, let alone `sum(x**2 for x in t) > n`.